# iOS `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a strange problem where when doing this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text]);
```

logs this

```
/var/mobile/Applications/C6E7B405-5A68-4729-AFA9-910E17AFE825/Documents/Downloads
```

which is what `self.pat` is, without the string being appended. This is in my `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath:` method, and the table view cell's text is being set before I do this, and is showing properly. `self.pat` is declared as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pat`, and I set the cell's text like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and I set `self.pat` in `viewDidAppear:animated:` and `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: your `textlabel` is definitely empty.

Comment: @CodaFi that is what the problem was, I just ended up using `[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in place of `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text`.

Comment: Please split your code up into multiple lines. It makes it so much easier to debug and read. Cramming 6 nested method calls into one line is a terrible practice. Declaring extra variables and splitting up the code will make your life so much easier.

Comment: In which method you are trying to call this append api..? UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; try the above line of code and make sure cell is not nill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this

```
[self.pat stringByAppendingPathComponent:[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

it works, so I guess that the textLabel wasn't being set quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is get the value of `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` in the context you're trying to use it here. My guess is that it's `nil` (because either `tableView` or `indexPath` is `nil`).

**UPDATE:**

As maddy points out in the comments, it can't be the case that `nil` is passed to `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` as it would throw an exception. And I think we'd need to see what's going on in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to really get to the bottom of this.

But, really, the more troubling thing here is that you're getting data from a view. In MVC design, all your data should come from the model. So really, rather than generating this path with the contents of a cell label, you should be getting the value from the same model used to populate the cell.

Comment: It can't be `nil`. Passing `nil` to `stringByAppendingPathComponent` will cause an exception.

Comment: Doh! Very true. Updated.